# Can column groupings be changed in an existing Excel with POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, grouping

I've been working with *Apache POI* for the past couple of month to create an *'Export to/ Import from Excel'* functionality for our application.

> **Note:** I used 3.9 but have no switched to 3.10-FINAL.

The typical use case is, that a user either downloads the empty template or exports existing data to an Excel file. He then makes changes to the data and uploads his file again.

To provided a detailed feedback for the user we use his uploaded Excel file and create a report file from it. This report file is a copy of the uploaded file with two additional columns that contain information about the data he imported. An error message that tells him why his data was not accepted, for example.

This requires to shift all columns to the right and add two new columns to the left. I implemented this and I even managed to move the cell comments with the columns. Now I'm stuck however, because I can't move the column groupings.

The template has a few columns grouped together and collapsed per default. Because we have 100+ columns this is supposed to make it easier for the user by hiding some seldom used columns.

During template creation I use the following code to create the groupings.

```
    SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer> group;

    sheet.setRowSumsRight(false);
    for (String groupId : groupMap.keySet()) {
        group = groupMap.get(groupId);

        sheet.groupColumn((group.getKey() + 1) + offset, group.getValue() + offset);
        sheet.setColumnGroupCollapsed(group.getValue() + offset, true);
    }
```

`group.getKey()` returns the leftmost column and `group.getValue()` the rightmost column of the group. The `offset` is always 0.
My idea was to use the same code with an `offset` of 2 to shift the groupings in the report file. Thinking that simply overwriting wouldn't work I tried to *ungroup* the columns first with this:

```
sheet.ungroupColumn(0, 130);
```

This is just an example. I tried several different approaches, like ungrouping all groups at once using the maximum range or ungrouping every group on my map.

Nothing worked as expected however. If I try to ungroup the column groupings it *breaks* the groupings instead and produces undesired effects. The column groups get split up into smaller groups instead of being removed from the Excel document. Some are actually removed but I found now way to make it work safely.

> **Note:** I'm using *XSSF* only.

I'm out of ideas and it looks to me like it's impossible for some reason to rewrite the column groupings using the standard *POI API*. In fact it seems as if the column grouping functionality only works properly with empty documents before they are filled with data.
I spent a lot of time googling the problem but found no solution and frankly barely any results that matched my problem. Either my *google-fu* left me or I'm the only one who has to bother with such a functionality.

I'm hoping someone here might a have an idea or solution to my problem, because I think this should be possible. What is the point of the `ungroupColumn` function otherwise?

> **Note:** I thought about using two different templates and simply copying the data since it seems to be no problem to create the groupings correctly when generating the template.
>   This would require several major changes to the code however (and I'm basically out of time) and would pose problems with one or two other requirements I have to fulfill. So this is more like a *Plan C* for me, which would be my last solution to the problem.

---

**Edit:**
For those interested, I went with the solution proposed by *Florian Rodler* as it proved to be a working solution/workaround for my problem. I modified his code slightly for this.

```
if (sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() > 0) {
  Row row = sheet.rowIterator().next();

  for (int i = row.getFirstCellNum(); i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
    sheet.ungroupColumn(i, i);
  }
}
```

This successfully removes all column groups/outlines from my Excel document. I then use the template creation code shown in my question with an `offset` greater than 2 to *move* (or rather recreate) the groups to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the way Apache POI treats column groups is broken and produces side effect, but I think there is a way to remove all the column groups in the sheet like this:

```
for (int i=first_column; i<=last_column; i++) {
    sheet.ungroupColumn(i,i);
}
```

If there is only on outline level, this will remove all the groups. If there are n outline levels you might need to repeat it n times to make sure every group gets removed.

Comment: It worked. Not pretty, but at least a working solution. Thank you! Funny thing is, I thought about trying this but after the rest failed, I thought _brute-forcing_ it wouldn't make a difference.